# Problem with external async function in vue mounted

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, vue-component, vuejs3

## What is the problem

I wanted to create an external async funtion and just assign what it returnes to value from state. As you can see I also pass to this function firebase reference and store, so I don't have to import it again in the js file. Another thing that I want is to **assign false to *state.isLoading*, but only after the async function is complited**. Console just gives me this

*Promise { "pending" }
​
: "fulfilled"
​
: Array [ {…} ]*

So there is my array, but I don't know how to get its value.

Thank you form your help!

## Vue Code

```
import {CreateUserFoldersList} from "@/path";
import {useStore} from 'vuex'
import {onMounted, reactive} from "vue";
import {useRouter} from 'vue-router'
import fire from "@/utilities/fire";

export default {
  name: "FlashcardsBrowser",
  setup() {
```

- Here I want to place returned value from funtion to var from state object

```
    onMounted(() => {
      state.Folders = CreateUserFoldersList(store.state.UserData.AuthUser.uid, fire)
      state.isLoading = false
    })

    const router = useRouter()
    const store = useStore()


    const state = reactive({
      Folders: [],
      isLoading: true,
      isShowingModal: false,
    })
    return {
      state
    }
```

#### External funtion

```
export async function CreateUserFoldersList(storeUserData, firebaseRef) {
    let mainFolder;
    await firebaseRef.database().ref(`UserData/${storeUserData}/Folders`).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
         const data = snapshot.val()

         let Folders = []
         if (data) {
             Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
                 Folders.push({
                     id: key,
                     name: data[key].name,
                     length: data[key].length
                 })
             })
         }
        mainFolder = Folders
     })
    return mainFolder
}
```

### I would be glad if you help thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try await to the function like so:

```js
 onMounted(async () => {
    state.Folders = await CreateUserFoldersList(store.state.UserData.AuthUser.uid, fire)
    state.isLoading = false
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
state.Folders = await CreateUserFoldersList(store.state.UserData.AuthUser.uid, fire)
```